# How should I interpret these parametric equations of orbit?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

> In my math book there are these parametric equations of the orbit/trajectory of a point $P$:
> $$\begin{cases}
> x(t)=\sin t\\
> y(t)=\sin 4t\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> along with a graph/picture of it on the $y$ and $x$ axis.
> Could anyone explain why it follows the path it does?

I unfortunately cant plot it on desmos or show a picture, so if anyone could do this, that would be great.

I thought about it, and since the x values are given by $sin(t)$, does this mean that the trajectory of $P$ first goes to the right, but after $sin(\pi)$ the $x$ values suddenly get negative, and the trajectory switches to the left of the $y$ axis?

So my question is in which direction does the orbit exactly go?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: I presume i can just plug in some values of t and determine the direction right?

Answer (score 1):

The figure you're looking at is determined by looking at an $x$-$y$ plane and by drawing out a path $(x(t),y(t))$ that depends on a parameter $t\in \mathbb{R}$, which you can intuitively understand to be time.

The coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are functions of the parameter $t$ given in your case by $x(t) =\sin(t)$ and $y(t)=\sin(4t)$. The figure $$\{(\sin(t),\sin(4t)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

is actually called a [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve). The direction and speed at which the figure is "drawn" depends on how you go trough the parameter $t$. If you start at $t=0$, you start at the origin $(0,0)$ and as $t$ increases, the point $(x(t),y(t))$ starts moving to the Northeast. However, you could just as well look at $$\{(\sin(-t),\sin(-4t)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

The curve in the $x$-$y$ plane will still be the same Lissajous curve, but if you start at $t=0$ and let $t$ increase and follow $(x(t),y(t))$, the point will move to the Southwest instead. In this case you're following the curve in the other direction.

So it all depends on $t$. In your original parametric equations, you are following the points by "walking" along the curve starting at the origin $(0,0)$ and moving to the Northeast. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUi8SnGGfG8) might help you as well to visualize this.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}
x=\sin t\\
y=\sin 4t\\
\end{cases};\;0\le t\le2\pi
$$
[image]